# Make div container auto-expand width to the left instead of the right when text is added

Tags: html, css

I have a little dropdown, which works just fine:

[image]

However, when more text is added to the dropdown, the div expands to the right, like so:

[image]

Whereas I'd rather it expand to the left.

**Markup/Blade** (I'm using Laravel):

```
<div class="status-dropdown-arrow pointer" id="status-dropdown-arrow-{{ $status->id }}" data-value="{{ $status->id }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 <ul class="fallback">
    @if (Auth::user()->isFollowing($status->user))      
     <a href="{{ route('get.following.add', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}"><li>Unfollow</li></a>
    @else 
     <a href="{{ route('get.following.add', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}"><li>Follow</li></a>    
    @endif
    <a href="{{ route('status.report', ['statusId' => $status->id]) }}"><li>Report</li></a>                     
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.status-dropdown-arrow {
float:right;
margin-top: -58px;
color:#b9adad;
}

.status-dropdown-arrow ul.fallback {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 5px;
display: none;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: #f6f4f4;
list-style: none;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: -72px;
}
```

How could I make the container expand to the left rather than the right?

Comment: You should set a wrapper inside your `.fallback` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: relative` on the parent and `right: 0` on the absolutely positioned child will align it to the right side of the parent, and the element will grow to the left.

Your `ul`/`li` structure is invalid, too. An `a` can't be a child of a `ul` - you should move the `a`'s inside the `li`'s

```css
.status-dropdown-arrow {
  float: right;
  color: #b9adad;
  position: relative;
}

.status-dropdown-arrow ul.fallback {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #f6f4f4;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="status-dropdown-arrow pointer">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <ul class="fallback">
    <li><a href="">Unfollow</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Follow</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a float left for your​ fallback class
, it might be taking the parent property of float right

Answer (score 0):

Set `rigth: 0` on `.status-dropdown-arrow ul.fallback` and `position: relative` on `.status-dropdown-arrow` should do the job.